# A question about typescript symbol as a object property identifier

Tags: typescript, object, key, symbols

```
peng@neo-laptop:~/ts-learnings$ tsc --version
Version 3.6.4
```

While the code snippet like this:

```js
const sym = Symbol('foo');

let o = {
    name: "Jessie Tom",
    age: 35
};

function extendObject(obj: any, sym: symbol, value: any) {
    obj[sym] = value;
}

extendObject(o, sym, 42);

console.log(Object.keys(o));
```

Got the result:

```
[
  "name",
  "age"
]
```

The problem is `sym` is not a object key. Why?

Answer (score 2):

That's just how Object.keys works. It does not return symbols. Use [Object.getOwnPropertySymbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) if you want symbols.

```js
const sym = Symbol('foo');

let o = {
    name: "Jessie Tom",
    age: 35,
};

function extendObject(obj, sym, value) {
    obj[sym] = value;
}

extendObject(o, sym, 42);

console.log(Object.keys(o));
const symbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(o)
console.log(symbols);
console.log(o[symbols[0]]);
```